# Steam Web API get Badge Image URL

Tags: php, json, api, badge, steam

So I'm looking to get the URL of the badge images from Steam.

**/IPlayerService/GetBadges/v1/** gives:

```
{
"response": {
    "badges": [
        {
            "badgeid": 2,
            "level": 2,
            "completion_time": 1374530451,
            "xp": 200,
            "scarcity": 1711283
        },
        {
            "badgeid": 8,
            "level": 1,
            "completion_time": 1356256226,
            "xp": 100,
            "scarcity": 741879
        },
        {
            "badgeid": 1,
            "appid": 245070,
            "level": 1,
            "completion_time": 1379186990,
            "xp": 100,
            "communityitemid": "227090978",
            "border_color": 0,
            "scarcity": 688570
        },
        {
            "badgeid": 1,
            "appid": 219150,
            "level": 1,
            "completion_time": 1379187097,
            "xp": 100,
            "communityitemid": "227093331",
            "border_color": 0,
            "scarcity": 101278
        },
    ]
    ,
    "player_xp": 1227,
    "player_level": 11,
    "player_xp_needed_to_level_up": 173,
    "player_xp_needed_current_level": 1200
} }
```

But the badge images are saved on:
http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/items/218620/d7ba194fac98cc5755fe7f08a8a7e2400acac43e.png

I can get the  from **/IPlayerService/GetBadges/v1/** but that only gives me:

```
http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/items/<appID>/d7ba194fac98cc5755fe7f08a8a7e2400acac43e.png
```

So how do I get the badge images of completed badges from a specific steam user?

**Sources**

- Steam Web API: http://steamcommunity.com/dev
- Steam Web API Wiki: [http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Category:WebAPI](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Category%3aWebAPI)
- xPaw Docs: http://lab.xpaw.me/steam_api_documentation.html
- Sample Badge Page: http://steamcommunity.com/id/TerryIGN/badges/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can Terry. I am having this same issue when trying to get weapon images for a similar game. I am having to download the images and store them on my server to then reference. They just simply haven't made the url available through there api.

Steam API is not great.

Comment: Ah that's a shame. Only option is to scrape data by myself but that will be a really slow process. Thanks for your reply tho :)