# Why can't I use php curl to get steam user profiles and how to get steam badge image?

Tags: php, curl, steam, badge

I am currently using php to develop a website about steam which can fetch the user's profile and make player cards and so on. I am using the Steam Web Api to help me getting the information I want. Problem is, when I intend to acquire the user's badges, I use the "IPlayerService/GetBadges/v1" api, and it returns a json data like this:

```
{
    "response": {
        "badges": [
            {
                "badgeid": 23,
                "level": 300,
                "completion_time": 1434209651,
                "xp": 125,
                "scarcity": 0
            },
            {
                "badgeid": 18,
                "level": 15,
                "completion_time": 1404061200,
                "xp": 100,
                "scarcity": 102167
            },
            {
                "badgeid": 2,
                "level": 3,
                "completion_time": 1457872741,
                "xp": 500,
                "scarcity": 1334304
            },
            {
                "badgeid": 13,
                "level": 57,
                "completion_time": 1356099851,
                "xp": 260,
                "scarcity": 5832743
            },
            {
                "badgeid": 1,
                "level": 3,
                "completion_time": 1356099851,
                "xp": 150,
                "scarcity": 76725893
            },
            {
                "badgeid": 1,
                "appid": 231430,
                "level": 3,
                "completion_time": 1455540973,
                "xp": 300,
                "communityitemid": "817099833",
                "border_color": 0,
                "scarcity": 20438
            },
            {
                "badgeid": 1,
                "appid": 24010,
                "level": 1,
                "completion_time": 1403487961,
                "xp": 100,
                "communityitemid": "828384582",
                "border_color": 0,
                "scarcity": 15404
            },
            {
                "badgeid": 1,
                "appid": 35450,
                "level": 1,
                "completion_time": 1403573788,
                "xp": 100,
                "communityitemid": "842044372",
                "border_color": 0,
                "scarcity": 122236
            },
            {
                "badgeid": 1,
                "appid": 63380,
                "level": 1,
                "completion_time": 1403574599,
                "xp": 100,
                "communityitemid": "842169975",
                "border_color": 0,
                "scarcity": 222048
            },
            {
                "badgeid": 1,
                "appid": 303700,
                "level": 1,
                "completion_time": 1403743093,
                "xp": 100,
                "communityitemid": "866824198",
                "border_color": 0,
                "scarcity": 998614
            },
            {
                "badgeid": 17,
                "appid": 335590,
                "level": 1,
                "completion_time": 1420075581,
                "xp": 100,
                "communityitemid": "1438441936",
                "border_color": 0,
                "scarcity": 858393
            },
            {
                "badgeid": 1,
                "appid": 105450,
                "level": 1,
                "completion_time": 1451207235,
                "xp": 100,
                "communityitemid": "2454848086",
                "border_color": 0,
                "scarcity": 49755
            },
            {
                "badgeid": 1,
                "appid": 220200,
                "level": 1,
                "completion_time": 1451207275,
                "xp": 100,
                "communityitemid": "2454853894",
                "border_color": 0,
                "scarcity": 100821
            },
            {
                "badgeid": 2,
                "appid": 425280,
                "level": 3,
                "completion_time": 1451805075,
                "xp": 300,
                "communityitemid": "2483562201",
                "border_color": 0,
                "scarcity": 297565
            },
            {
                "badgeid": 1,
                "appid": 206440,
                "level": 1,
                "completion_time": 1451805331,
                "xp": 100,
                "communityitemid": "2549522337",
                "border_color": 0,
                "scarcity": 43807
            },
            {
                "badgeid": 1,
                "appid": 391220,
                "level": 1,
                "completion_time": 1455372224,
                "xp": 100,
                "communityitemid": "2699515873",
                "border_color": 0,
                "scarcity": 16843
            },
            {
                "badgeid": 1,
                "appid": 287390,
                "level": 1,
                "completion_time": 1457355907,
                "xp": 100,
                "communityitemid": "2764853882",
                "border_color": 0,
                "scarcity": 35158
            }
        ]
        ,
        "player_xp": 2735,
        "player_level": 18,
        "player_xp_needed_to_level_up": 65,
        "player_xp_needed_current_level": 2600
    }
}
```

This returned data only tells me about the badgeid and appid, and says nothing about the url of the badge image. I checked the badge image on steam, it's url is like http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/items/105450/**472be31927c4e77721fcba33bbd04b1331272e7e**.png

so I can not get the url just by the appid.
Since the steam web api can not fulfill my intention, I try to use php curl the request the steam user's profile page and badge page to acquire the information I need, and my code is:

```
$url='http://steamcommunity.com/profile/76561198078931851';
$postFields='';
$cookie='';
$header=array('Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*//*;q=0.8', 'Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch', 'Accept-Language:zh-CN,zh;q=0.8', 'Cache-Control:max-age=0', 'Connection:keep-alive','Host:steamcommunity.com', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1','User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36');

$btch=curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($btch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
curl_setopt($btch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($btch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($btch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
curl_setopt($btch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate,sdch');          //  防止乱码
curl_setopt($btch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($btch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($btch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($btch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);

try{       
       $result=curl_exec($btch);
}            
catch(exception $e)  
{              
       echo $e->getMessage();
} 
if(!$result)
{
    echo 'false!';
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';

curl_close($btch);
```

The curl did work, but steam never return the user's profile page and instead always redirects the request to the homepage of steam community and asks me to login.Therefore I can not proceed to fetch user profile. 
I read the following related question:
[Steam Web API get Badge Image URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597265/steam-web-api-get-badge-image-url)
Does anybody knows anything about how to solve this problem and could you provide me some help? Great thanks in advance!

Comment: I suppose the Steam Web API requires user to be logged in, to serve it's profile page. It does not sound as unexpected.... :-)

Comment: @MarcoS Thanks for your comment but maybe you misunderstood me. 1 It's when I use php curl directly request the steam user profile page (like http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198119890595) that I am asked to log in, not when I use the steam web api. The steam web api works just fine, it just can't provide the information I need. 2 when I use a web browser (I tried chrome, edge and ie) to visit a user profile page, I am not asked to log in and I can still get all the content. I even clear all my cookies to make sure I am not logged in, and it still works. That's the most confusing part.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Steam Web API; I did just try to give a prompt from outside, supposing it could be a lapse of yours... :-(

Comment: @MarcoS It's quite all right:) I must have some lapses elsewhere. Again, thanks for your concern and comment!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I find a way myself to solve the problem...just using 
`file_get_contents()` instead of curl to request the steam user profile page. :)